What does "no" refer to?
Gwen steps through a portal into Miles's room and asks if this is
where he grew up. Miles confirms, adding that his dorm room is more
adult. Gwen's attention is drawn to a boxed anime action figure on
his shelf:

Gwen: Cool. Yeah, no, I used to play with these when I was younger,
too.
Miles: Uh, this is-- that's a, that's a collectible.

What does "no" refer to?

+1 It's a good question. Valorum's answer makes plain that there's nuance to learn about there. I am tolerably good at explaining English language use to my ELL friends, and have specifically been stumped by explaining expressions like "Yeah, no, yeah" and "No, yeah, no".

@Lexible - I thought it was a good question too. If English isn't your primary language, these sorts of nuances can be weird and confusing and accessing the script isn't going to help you.

I'm seeing more than one English language question (unrelated to scifi) from this user. I'd suggest they ask in english.stackexchange rather than here, since they specialize in this kind of questions over there, and here it's just an accident that they happen to occur in Spiderman.

"Yeah, no" is referred to by linguists as a discourse marker. Edwin Battistella, Professor of Humanities (and world-renowned specialist in Linguistics) describes it thusly;

It is wrong to think of “yeah no” as an oxymoron and a sign of
inarticulate confusion. “Yeah no” is what linguists call a discourse
marker. Discourse markers are usually short and sometime vague-seeming
parts of a sentence which serve semantic, expressive, and practical
functions in speech. They can indicate assent or dissent (or sometimes
both). They can indicate attention, sarcasm, hedging, self-effacement,
or face-saving.
Where did the phrase “yeah no” come from?

In this instance, the usage seems to be broad agreement, in line with the way that the word structure is most frequently used. Miles says that his room at college is more adult. Gwen is agreeing with him that this room looks like it's a child's room.

Miles: My dorm room is very adult
Gwen: ["Yes, I can see that. You clearly have dollies on your shelves, like I did when I was a little girl"]

The irony is, of course, that the one feature she picks out is actually something that he still values, an anime figurine in its box.

+1 See also "Yeah, no, yeah" and "No, yeah, no".
